# Strange PHP loop scope what am i missing?

Tags: php, loops

I have here 3 differen types of arrays/objects

First:

```
$myObj = [
    (object) [
        'fritz'   => 1,
        'michael' => 2,
        'hans'    => 3,
        'jurgen'  => 4,
    ]
];

foreach ( $myObj as $key => $val ) {
    $val->michael = 'lorem ipsum...';
}

print_r( $myObj );
```

outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [fritz] => 1
            [michael] => lorem ipsum...
            [hans] => 3
            [jurgen] => 4
        )
)
```

Second:

```
$myArr = [
    [
        'fritz'   => 1,
        'michael' => 2,
        'hans'    => 3,
        'jurgen'  => 4,
    ]
];


foreach ( $myArr as $key => $val ) {
    $val['michael'] = 'lorem ipsum...';
}

print_r( $myArr );
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [fritz] => 1
            [michael] => 2
            [hans] => 3
            [jurgen] => 4
        )
)
```

Why is in the first example the $myObj changed infact it has been never accessed inside the loop. As i know loops are working with a copy and never changes the original. What am i missing?
Is there a diference between arrays and object access durring the loop?

Comment: Because objects are always passed __by reference__.

Comment: You point me to the right direction for Google. Thank you.